# How to add view like this

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

[image]

As shown click the top three buttons will pop up a view on the basic view. What the view is? CALayer? Or just a small size UITableView? How to implement this?

Comment: You have to prepare an imageview like that add it by animataing

Comment: No offense, but it seems to me like you have no idea of what you are asking... If I were you, I'd read about how views and view controllers work.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem with this question? you are assuming things about the guy that you can not prove in any way. he saw something and he wish to understand what could it be. @'it seems to me like you have no idea of what you are asking', well that why he got here for didn't he? before you guy's vote down people, try to remember the day's you didn't have a clue in coding.

Comment: @shannoga Thanks for your understand!!! I'll still improve myself!!! Thank you indeed!

Comment: @shannoga I made an educated guess based on the fact that he thinks a CALayer is a view, and the fact that once you know how views and view controllers work, it's pretty easy to figure out how to lay a view on top of a view controller. SO is not a place to learn how to code, it's a place to find help when you have tried a lot of things and you can't work something out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belevie this is a custom view that contains a table view inside it. it is very simple to implement that, As this is not a full tutorial I can imagine the basic steps I would do:

the shape could be a combination of layers or more reasonable drawn with Quartz2D:

I would do it this way:

1. create view and draw the frame with a `BezierPath` in the  `drawRect`:

   ```
   + (UIBezierPath *)bezierPathWithRoundedRect:(CGRect)rect cornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius
   ```
2. draw the top black bar and the title on the top.
3. draw the top triangle and add to the view a property that will set the position according to the button position. then you could conditionally change the draw position of the triangle.
4. add a sub view of a table view and assign the view as a DataSource and a Delegate of it, and then do all the table view implementation.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

the control is like a UIPopoverController - but UIPopoverController is limited to iPad only. here's a source which have generic/custom implementation that will help you creating similar view.

https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover

Comment: That looks like an awesome open-source project, I will have to check it out

Answer (score 0):

It's just a custom view. There is probably a UITableView embedded in the view for the friend request list.